# Pytesseract not reading some characters properly

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract, poppler

I have an OCR built with Pytesseract, where the data is grabbed from a PDF file that's made out of PNG pages, it's converted via poppler and then scanned. The script works well for the most part, but I have an issue with reading strings of characters for car license plates (they are in plain text, as a part of the data). Sometimes the "O" replaces the "0", "Z" replaces "7" and so on.

I've tried changing the config, and binarizing the image but to no avail. Is there something I'm missing here? Let me know what other info could I give out and I'll provide it as soon as I can

Comment: Could you provide simple example of code with image of page where the problem occure . That would help to test the use case and try solve it

Comment: Tesseract doc: [Improving the quality of the output | tessdoc](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Comment: if text is too small then it may have problem. If text is too big then it may have problem too. If there is too small top margin and/or bottom margin then it may tread `Z` as `7` or `/`, and `7` as `/`

Comment: Here's the sample image I'm working with (Sensitive data censored) [link](https://easyupload.io/fnef3u) As for the code, I'm using Py2PDF to read the PDF into PNG which I'm then parsing using Tesseract, I've tried all the PSM's and none of them are working correctly for me @HamzaNABIL

Comment: you could add this in question - more people will see it, so more people may help you. And put image directly in question, not link to external portal.